# JAVA Problems with if statement? Cannot display end result correctly.

Tags: java

I am trying to print "tuition will increase" when there are at least three students that averaged 70%+ and print "tuition will not increase" if there are less than 3 students that averaged 70%+. My problem is, even when the average is not above 70%, the program will print "tuition will increase." I'm not sure what I've done wrong. I've tried changing the if statement and I feel like I'm missing something very simple.

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Create Scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

        // Create array to store 5 students and 3 classes per student
        int[][] grades = new int[5][3]; 

        // Create array to store students first and last name
        String[] names = new String[5]; 

        // Create array to store average scores
        double[] avgScores = new double[5]; 

        // Prompt user to input name
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the student's first and last name: ");
            names[i] = input.nextLine(); 
        }


        double average = 0; 
        int score; // student's grade
        int finalGrade = 0; // collective grades
        int goodStudents = 0; // students that received average of 70+

        // Prompt user to input grades using nested for loop
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) // from student 1 to student 5
        {
            for (int k = 0; k <= 2; k++) // from class 1 to class 3 
            {
                System.out.print("Enter the grade for class " + (k + 1) + " " + "for student "
                        + (i + 1) + " : "); 
                grades[i][k] = input.nextInt();

                score = grades[i][k]; 
                finalGrade = finalGrade + score; 
            }

            // Calculate the average score for the 3 classes
            avgScores[i] = finalGrade / 3; 

            finalGrade = 0; // reset 
        }   
            for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++)
            {
                if (avgScores[j] < 70)
                {
                    goodStudents++; 
                }

        }

        // count the number of students that have 70+ average

            if (goodStudents >= 3)
            {
                System.out.println("Tuition will be increased by 10% next semester.");
            } else if (goodStudents < 3)
            {
                System.out.println("Tuition will not be increased.");
            }   

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to figure out what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your logic is incorrect here

```
if (avgScores[j] < 70) 
{
    goodStudents++; 
}
```

Your criteria was *at least three students that averaged 70%+*, but you are testing for `< 70`. Change it like,

```
if (avgScores[j] >= 70) 
{
    goodStudents++; 
}
```

Comment: it was a problem related with a percentage calculation, but not in the logic

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a max value of score and get a percentage(70%) of it, later in the condition you have to use that.
Here is one of the way:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Dot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create Scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int max_score = 5;  // Max score 
        double persn = 5 *0.7; // 0.7 is 70%
        // Create array to store 5 students and 3 classes per student
        int[][] grades = new int[5][3];

        // Create array to store students first and last name
        String[] names = new String[5];

        // Create array to store average scores
        double[] avgScores = new double[5];

        // Prompt user to input name
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter the student's first and last name: ");
            names[i] = input.nextLine();
        }

        double average = 0;
        int finalGrade = 0; // collective grades
        int goodStudents = 0; // students that received average of 70+

        // Prompt user to input grades using nested for loop
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) // from student 1 to student 5
        {
            for (int k = 0; k <= 2; k++) // from class 1 to class 3 
            {
                System.out.print("Enter the grade for class (max = )"+max_score+ + (k + 1) + " " + "for student "
                        + (i + 1) + " : ");
                grades[i][k] = input.nextInt();

                finalGrade += grades[i][k];
            }

            // Calculate the average score for the 3 classes
            avgScores[i] = finalGrade / 3.0;

            finalGrade = 0; // reset 
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if (avgScores[j] <= persn) {   //here is 70% as persn
                goodStudents++;
            }

        }

        // count the number of students that have 70+ average
        if (goodStudents >= 3) {
            System.out.println("Tuition will be increased by 10% next semester.");
        } else if (goodStudents < 3) {
            System.out.println("Tuition will not be increased.");
        }
    }
}
```